# Does cut return any fields if separator does not exist

Tags: cut

I executed

```
cut -d '~' -f 2 on input

RSC
AED
FCB
A~RS
```

and I obtained

```
RSC
AED
FCB
RS
```

I realized that cut will return entire line if the delimiter does not exist.
It is that true?

Comment: Why not try it and see?  Run the command `cut -d '~' -f 2` at a prompt, type in some lines and see what gets printed.

Comment: As specified in question I ran some examples and I realized that behavior. I wanted to be sure that I was right.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's true. POSIX define [cut -f](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cut.html#tag_20_28_04) option as:

> -f  list
>
> Cut based on a list of fields, assumed to be separated in the file by
>   a delimiter character (see -d). Each selected field shall be output.
>   Output fields shall be separated by a single occurrence of the field
>   delimiter character. **Lines with no field delimiters shall be passed
>   through intact, unless -s is specified**. It shall not be an error to
>   select fields not present in the input line.

and this repeated again in `-s`:

> -s
>
> Suppress lines with no delimiter characters, when used with the -f
>   option. Unless specified, **lines with no delimiters shall be passed
>   through untouched**.

Comment: Thank you. I read the documentation, but I missed those details. I should read more carefully next time.